# Join elements from sublists

Tags: list, haskell

Given a square array, is there a way to use applicative style or similar to "zip" together the first element from each `[[a]]`, followed by the second element, and so on?

```hs
> let xss = [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]] :: [[Int]]
> map (\i -> map (!! i) xss) [0..length xss - 1]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I wrote the above solution for a programming challenge website, but I'm not happy with the `map (!! i)` or the `[0..length xs - 1]`. Is there a more advanced way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for [`Data.List.transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose).

Comment: Ah, of course!  Thank you! 

Comment: @Jubobs why don't you answer the question? that way it gets cleared from the list of unanswered questions, and can be accepted?

Comment: @JulianLeviston I honestly thought this would be promptly closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Data.List.transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) is right up your alley.

Tip: when looking for functions that might already be implemented somewhere, try [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), a nifty Haskell-API search engine. In your particular case, [searching for `[[a]] -> [[a]]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) returns `Data.List.transpose` as the top result.